# Summation with index in the middle of the summand. What does it mean?

Tags: commutative-algebra, notation

[image]

I don't know what the summation in the above pic is saying.

Assume that the x's (1 to n) shown above are numbers that have already been assigned values. n is a fixed value.

(I found this in Atiyah-Macdonald in a proof of some proposition. I tried looking at alternate proofs of the proposition online seeking an explanation for what the summation notation meant but all the proofs were really different from the one in the book.)

Comment: I don't know exactly what you're asking but note that $x_i$ is missing which is one of possible reasons to emphasize "the middle" like this.

Comment: This means: $(x_2x_3\ldots x_n)+(x_1x_3\ldots x_n)+(x_1x_2x_4\ldots x_n)+\dotsb + (x_1x_2\ldots x_{n-1})$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note, that at every summation step $i$, $x_i$ is missing in the product, so I'd suggest that, as the index counts upwards, the missed out value in the product moves through the $x_i's$, i.e.

$$\sum_{i=1}^nx_1x_2\dots x_{i-1}x_{i+1}\dots x_n= (x_2\dots x_n) + (x_1x_3\dots x_n)+\dots +(x_1\dots x_{n-1})$$

Or, in a little more compact notation:

$$\sum_{i=1}^nx_1x_2\dots x_{i-1}x_{i+1}\dots x_n=\sum_{i=1}^n\prod_{j\leq n, j\neq i}x_j=\prod_{j\leq n, j\neq 1}x_j+\dots +\prod_{j\leq n, j\neq n}x_j$$

Comment: I know it isn't proper etiquette to respond with non-constructive comments, but cheers! I also need to rethink my life choices...

Comment: @Barycentric_Bash To continue "non-proper etiquette", let me ask, why do you need to rethink you life choices?

Comment: I have to confess that I spent upwards of ~30 min trying to find a 'solution' to my problem because i didn't see the missing xi

Comment: @Barycentric_Bash Notation is the burden all of us have to carry when doing mathematics. The foremost important thing is to understand. So, I think, don't worry to much about that.